# How do I create a form inside popup in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, list

I want to create a behavior similar to what is expressed below:

1. Have a list of animal shelters (as an example)
2. Press a button to create a new one (html form) (Frame 1)
3. Add animals (objects with multiple features) to it (Frame 2)
4. Have a list of those objects in the form (Frame 3)
5. Have a new animal shelter in my list (Frame 4)

**Problem 1**
The little dialog can't be an extra html form because a form in another form is not possible.

**Problem 2**
Since each animal has multiple features it wouldn't look nice to dynamically add text fields to the form with javascript.

[image: what I want to do]

Comment: this needs to be spread out over many questions it is very broad.  You want a search panel people can type and pull up a paginated results of shelters?

Comment: The animal shelters where just an example. What I'm actually interested in is the behavior explained above. I have a form and in that form I want to add something like another form. Because I know this isn't possible I am searching for an alternative. I'm sorry that I'm not that precise, I'm not a native speaker. Feel free to completely change the text. Everything I want is explained in the picture (The last frame is something like the main menu, in frames 1-3 you can see the first form and in frame 2 there's the 'inner form')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. Yaay!

First I created the main form

```
<form action="/path/to/action.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" required>
    <input type="text" name="address" required>

    <span id="add-animal">+</span>
    <select id="animals" name="animals[]" multiple></select>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I also created a second form

```
<div id="animal-form">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="animalname" required>
        <input type="number" id="animalage" required>
    </form>
</div>
```

For the rest I used jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var animalname = $("#animalname");
    var animalage = $("#animalage");

    dialog = $("#animal-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: false,
        buttons: {
            "Add": addAnimal,
            "Cancel": function() {
                dialog.dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            form[0].reset();
        }
    });

    form = dialog.find("form");

    $("#add-animal").on("click", function() {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });

    function addAnimal() {
        var animals = document.getElementById("animals");

        var animal = document.createElement("option");
        animal.text = animalname.val();
        animal.setAttribute("value", animalage.val() + ":" + animalname.val()); // Encode all values into one value that can be passed
        animal.setAttribute("selected", ""); // select it because it's in a <select> and has to be passed

        animals.add(animal);
        dialog.dialog("close");

        return true;
    }
});
```

Basically I copied the source code (you can get that by entering the debugger, in firefox that means hitting the F12 key) from an example I found on [jqueryui.com](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal-form.html) and adjusted it a bit.